# Expresión regular para validar fecha y hora (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)

Tags: php, regex, validación

Buenas a todos.

Estuve buscando un rato alguna expresión regular para validar el formato de fecha y hora, **dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm** o **dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm** o similar, pero las que encontré eran incompletas o cumplian las condiciones solo parcialmente u otros formatos de fecha.

Os dejo la base desde las que estoy haciendo pruebas. Actualmente solo es válido para fechas:

(https://regex101.com/r/yVN3p2/1)

```
^([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\/|-)([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])\2(\d{4})(\s)([0-1][1-9]|[2][0-3])(:)([0-5][0-9])$
```

Comment: Más que validación sería extracción, ¿no? Porque con una regex puedes validar la cantidad de enteros, máximos y mínimos pero no puedes validar que en febrero el máximo es 28 o 29 si bisiesto.

Comment: @erknrio como poder validar, se puede --> https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59516/127

Comment: ¿Quieres una validación aproximada o real? Es decir, ¿quieres comprobar que la fecha existe de verdad? Por ejemplo, el 31 de abril no existe, pero el 29 de febrero (en los años bisiestos) a veces existe y otras veces no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tomando la expresión regular de la pregunta como base podemos crear las siguiente validaciones:

Fecha: **dd/mm/yyyy** o **dd-mm-yyyy**

https://regex101.com/r/yVN3p2/7

```
^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\/|-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2(\d{4})$
```

Fecha, hora y minuto: **dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm** o **dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm**

https://regex101.com/r/yVN3p2/9

```
^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\/|-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2(\d{4})(\s)([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])(:)([0-5][0-9])$
```

Fecha, hora, min, seg: **dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss** o **dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss**

https://regex101.com/r/yVN3p2/10

```
^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\/|-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2(\d{4})(\s)([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])(:)([0-5][0-9])(:)([0-5][0-9])$
```

Un ejemplo de validación con PHP podría ser el sigiente

```
$regexFecha = '/^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\/|-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2(\d{4})(\s)([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])(:)([0-5][0-9])$/';

$fecha = '27/05/2017 23:00';
if ( !preg_match($regexFecha, $fecha, $matchFecha) ) {
        echo 'Fecha no válida';
}
else
{
    echo 'Fecha válida';
    print_r($matchFecha);
    /*
    array:9 [
      0 => "27/05/2017 23:00"
      1 => "27"
      2 => "/"
      3 => "05"
      4 => "2017"
      5 => " "
      6 => "23"
      7 => ":"
      8 => "00"
    ]
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice 2 expresiones regulares que validan las fechas, están mejoradas, abajo dejo más documentación.

- Validación de fecha en formato: AAAA-MM-DD, esta expresión regular no permite fechas erróneas como 30 y 31 de febrero o 29 de Febrero en un año que no fue o será Bisiesto:

  ```
  ^(19|20)(((([02468][048])|([13579][26]))-02-29)|(\d{2})-((02-((0[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8]))|((((0[13456789])|1[012]))-((0[1-9])|((1|2)\d)|30))|(((0[13578])|(1[02]))-31)))$
  ```
- Validación de fecha en formato: AAAA-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS, esta expresión regular no permite fechas erróneas como 30 y 31 de febrero o 29 de Febrero en un año que no fue o será Bisiesto, el formato de horas es de 24 horas:

  ```
  ^(19|20)(((([02468][048])|([13579][26]))-02-29)|(\d{2})-((02-((0[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8]))|((((0[13456789])|1[012]))-((0[1-9])|((1|2)\d)|30))|(((0[13578])|(1[02]))-31)))[Tt](([0-1]\d)|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5]\d){2}$
  ```

---

Estas dos expresiones regulares son una combinación de las siguientes expresiones regulares:

Validación de hora formato 24 horas sin segundos:

```
^(([0-1]\d)|(2[0-3])):[0-5]\d$
```

Validación de hora formato 24 horas con segundos:

```
^(([0-1]\d)|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5]\d){2}$
```

Validación de hora formato 12 horas sin segundos:

```
^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2])):[0-5]\d[aApP][mM]$
```

Validación de hora formato 12 horas con segundos:

```
^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(:[0-5]\d){2}[aApP][mM]$
```