# If en Regex sigue entrando en la condición falsa cuando se debería cumplir la verdadera

Tags: regex, pcre

Alguien me pueda ayudar con los if en regex estoy usando un compilador de regex he hice esto

```
^\d{2}(02)?(?(1)(0\d$|1\d$|2[0-8]$)|(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0\d$|1\d$|2\d$|3[0-1]$))
```

es para validar fechas AAMMDD correctas ya que febrero solo tiene 28 días pero el if me da un error, no de sintaxis si no lógico, ejemplo:

si yo pongo 200230 esto me lo pone correcto(aunque no debería ser correcto ya que febrero no tiene 30 dias) porque entra a la condición del if ya que si cumplió con tener un 02 después de los 2 dígitos del principio:

```
//entra aqui si el mes es 02 y valida que el día sea menor que 29
 (02)?(?(1)(0\d$|1\d$|2[0-8]$)|
```

como el día es 30 por alguna razón que desconozco se sale de este:

```
(?(1)(0\d|1\d|2[0-8])
```

y entra al segundo:

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0\d$|1\d$|2\d$|3[0-1]$)
```

y da match ¿alguien sabe por que no me funciona bien el if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda tu lógica está perfecta hasta que llegás a decir "*por alguna razón que desconozco*".

Te cuento esa razón siguiendo el paso a paso que hace el motor de regex:

1. Coincide con `(02)?`
2. Entra en la parte *verdadera* del IF
3. **FALLA**

¿Qué pasa acá, al igual que con cualquier construcción de regex cuando falla?
Hace *[backtracking](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129291/193460)*. Es decir, vuelve para atrás para seguir intentando otras combinaciones que podrían dar una coincidencia.

¿Qué es lo que intenta?

4. Intenta coincidir con `(02)?` repetido 0 veces (por el `?`). O sea, no coincidir con ese grupo 1.
5. Y bueno... el resto es historia... perfectamente puede coincidir con el resto, porque no captura el grupo 1, entra en la parte *falsa* del IF, `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])` permite que coincida con `"02"`, y coincide con todo.

---

---

Hay muchísimas formas de corregirlo, van algunas a modo de ejemplo:

- ¿Leíste sobre [cuantificadores posesivos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)? Es un `+` a continuación de un cuantificador. Hacen que si coincidió con una cantidad de repeticiones y más tarde falla, no intente con menos repeticiones. Es decir, que si coincidió con `(02)?+`, no pueda intentar con 0 repeticiones cuando vuelve por backtracking. Ese `+` de más te arregla el problema.

  ```
  ^\d{2}(02)?+(?(1)([01]\d|2[0-8])|(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-2]\d|3[0-1]))$
  ```
- ¿Viste que un IF puede preguntar por un grupo capturado o sino usar un lookahead? Bueno...

  ```
  ^\d{2}(?(?=02)02([01]\d|2[0-8])|(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-2]\d|3[0-1]))$
  ```
- ¿Querés hacer lo mismo sin un IF? Sólo es cuestión de armar las 2 alternativas, que sean excluyentes entre sí (una con febrero y la otra que no permita febrero de ninguna manera). `(0[13-9]|1[0-2])` coincide con todos los meses menos el 02.

  ```
  ^\d{2}(02([01]\d|2[0-8])|(0[13-9]|1[0-2])([0-2]\d|3[0-1]))$
  ```
- Febrero tiene 29 días en [años bisiestos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1o_bisiesto). ¿Querés volarte la cabeza? Lee esta pregunta: [Validar una fecha dd/mm/aaaa con expresiones regulares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59516/193460) y fijate si podés adaptarla a aammdd.