# Expresión regular para rango de valores de fechas en R

Tags: r, regex, date

Me gustaría obtener un vector que me indicara si una cadena de caracteres tiene el formato adecuado de fecha o no. Los días deben ir del 01 al 31, los meses del 01 al 12 y los años del 2022 al 2024. Solo deberían aparecer como TRUE las fechas que cumplan esos criterios. Para los meses lo he conseguido la expresión regular adecuada pero para los días y años no se como hacerlo.

El código que he usado es:

```
mystring <- c("25/12/1995","14/04/2023","04/14/2022","32/24/3022")
grepl("[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]/0[1-9]|1[0-2]/[2022-2024]", mystring)
```

Lo que quiero conseguir con la expresión regular adecuada es:

```
[1] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Qué es lo que falla en tu regex? Dos conceptos a tener en cuenta:

1. `[2022-2024]` coincide con un único caracter que puede ser 0, 2 o 4. Para coincidir con un número entre 2022 y 2024 deberías usar `202[2-4]`.
2. La `|` tiene la precedencia más baja, con lo cual algo como `1|2/3|4/202[2-4]` coincide simplemente con `1` o con `2/3` o con algo como `4/2022`, pero son opciones independientes... Para evitar eso, hay que agrupar con paréntesis. En el ejemplo simplificado sería `(1|2)/(3|4)/202[2-4]`.

#### Validación básica

Si tomamos literalmente la validación que estás pidiendo, el patrón sería:

```
^(0?[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/202[2-4]$
```

Como ves, se cubre cada opción, caracter por caracter (no existen estructuras para especificar rangos numéricos). Y este patrón incluso permitiría que ingresen `31` en meses que tienen 30 días, sin siquiera mencionar el tema de febrero y años bisiestos.

#### Validación completa con regex

La expresión que cumple en validar todas las fechas posibles ya fue escrita muchas veces. Googleala o lee la respuesta en este mismo sitio a [Validar una fecha dd/mm/aaaa con expresiones regulares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59516/193460). El patrón de esa respuesta es

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[/](?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:29|30)[/](?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])|31[/](?:0?[13578]|1[02]))[/](?:0{2,3}[1-9]|0{1,2}[1-9]\d|0?[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3})|29[/]0?2[/](?:\d{1,2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:0?[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])00))$
```

#### Aunque es ridículo validar una fecha con regex

En vez de entrar en una maraña sin sentido, usá las herramientas pensadas para procesar fechas dentro del lenguaje. Tan simple como

```
fecha <- NA
fecha <- as.Date(texto, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

En donde `fecha` seguirá siendo `NA` a menos que pases un `texto` que pueda interpretar como fecha válida.